# How do I switch back to Windows 8?

Tags: sudo, os-prober

Okay so I am taking an online course to learn Linux and Ubuntu. On my desktop that has windows 8.1, I downloaded Ubuntu and then watched a couple of videos to make sure that I partitioned the drive for Ubuntu. I picked the third option on the installation prompt, which said to choose your own. I dont know what exactly it says but I double checked to make sure that it was not going to install Ubuntu only and delete Windows 8.1. SO, I partitioned it in the installation prompt and made sub folders for the ram and etc. Then, I installed Ubuntu. It ran fine. But, I wanted to go back to Windows 8.1 and after restarting the computer; I am unable to do that. What do I do to go back to Windows 8.1? Is there a way? Because I do not have backup in a CD of the operating system? Please reply fast! Thanks

I did not have the option of running in alongside windows 8. Otherwise I would have.

I looked for the Grub menu, but in the entry, Windows 8.1 is not available. But I know it is still on the hard drive because I am able to go to the workforce of my computer from Ubuntu.

```
1sblk sudo os-prober
```

Okay so I entered the commands in the terminal
this is what I got with the first command of `lsblk`:

```
SDA 8:0  O   1.8t   0disk
-sda 8:1  0 476 m   0 part (swap)
-sda2 8:2 0 18.6g   0 part /
-sda 3 8:3  0 18.6  part/home
-sda 4  8:4  0 954 m 0 part/boot/efi
sro  11:0 1 1024 0 ram
```

Comment: You messed something up. It's always a bad idea to install OS without making a backup. It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to uninstall ubuntu or fix it? Ubuntu documentation is very clear, and the installation process couldn't be simpler. I don't know how on Earth could you mess up something as simple as that. And why didn't you use "Install ubuntu alongside windows" option? It does all the partitioning for you and simplyfies the whole process. My grandmother can install ubuntu  with such a simple installation wizard.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of `lsblk` and `sudo os-prober`. It might be that you have installed it and not deleted Windows 8, but a GRUB menu entry wasn't created.

Comment: What @muru ment is to go to the ubuntu, press Ctrl+alt+t, enter those commands in the treminal that will open, and give the output.

Comment: okay I will do that and let you know

Answer (score 0):

you say u don't have a backup cd.
Well,stuff like this happens. I'm not an expert but u could reinstall windows 8.

If you don't have a windows 8 cd you can get it from microsoft i guess, from what i have heard, or from the manufacturer of your computer (that is if the computer came with win 8 pre-installed.

If that doesn't work idk where you can get a free copy of win 8, but i do know you can get an ISO of windows 7 from here (original, straight from microsoft): http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/cannot-find-digital-river-download-site/66a8439b-0d16-4b70-92f7-1c8486a46ebf

It's better than nothing...